# Get tennis game's state using scala

Tags: scala

I am developing a scala function called `TennisGameStatus` which returns the state of tennis games between two players.
To remind, here are the rules of tennis games :

```
 - 1st gain: 15 pts
 - 2nd gain: 30 pts
 - 3rd gain: 40 pts
```

if both players get 40 scores, then, there are many states :

```
 - "DEUCE" if both are equal to the same score
 - "ADVANTAGE" is attributed to the player who wins **ONE** additional point to the 40 scores.
 - "WIN" is attributed to the player who wins **TWO** times after the 40 scores.
```

The result should be like this:

[image]

So, I developed this function :

```
def TennisGameStatus(nameP1 : String, nameP2: String, wins: Array[String]): String = {
  var scoreP1 = wins.count(x => x == nameP1)
  var scoreP2 = wins.count(x => x == nameP2)
  var Etat40P1 = wins.count(x => x == nameP1) >= 3
  var Etat40P2 = wins.count(x => x == nameP2) >= 3
  val valeursS40 = (5, 6)

  if (scoreP1 > scoreP2 && (1 <= (wins.length) ) && ((wins.length) < 3)) {
    return nameP1.concat((scoreP1 * 15).toString).concat(" ").concat(nameP2.concat((scoreP2 * 15).toString));
  }
  else if (scoreP2 > scoreP1 && (1 <= (wins.length) ) && ((wins.length) < 3)) {
    return nameP2.concat((scoreP2 * 15).toString).concat(" ").concat(nameP1.concat((scoreP1 * 15).toString));
  }
  else if (scoreP1 == scoreP2) {
    scoreP1 match {
      case 0
      => return nameP1.concat((scoreP1 * 15).toString).concat(" ").concat(nameP2.concat((scoreP2 * 15).toString));
      case 1
      => return "15a";
      case 2
      => return "30a";
      case 3
      => return "DEUCE";
    }
  }
  else if (scoreP1 > scoreP2 && valeursS40.canEqual(scoreP1) && Etat40P1.equals(true) && Etat40P2.equals(true)) {
    scoreP1 match {
      case 5
      => return nameP1.concat("ADVANTAGDE");
      case 6
      => return nameP1.concat("WIN");
    }
  }
  else if (scoreP2 > scoreP1 && valeursS40.canEqual(scoreP2) && Etat40P1.equals(true) && Etat40P2.equals(true)) {
    scoreP2 match {
      case 5
      => return nameP2.concat("ADVANTAGDE");
      case 6
      => return nameP2.concat("WIN");
    }
  }
  else
    return ""
}
```

But I think that my function is not optimized and it does not include functional operations provided by scala. Any help please ?

Answer (score 2):

You're right. This is not idiomatic Scala code for many reasons.

- The semicolons `;` aren't needed. Remove them.
- Experienced Scala programmers never use the `return` keyword. Remove them. They aren't needed.
- Idiomatic Scala avoids mutables, so you seldom see any `var` variables. Your `score` and `Etat` variables are initialized and never changed so they should be `val`s.

But the *real* problem is that the code doesn't work. I've encountered many input scenarios that don't produce the correct, or any, output.

I think the core of the problem comes from the complex and confusing `if` conditions you're testing for. It seems to me that the flow would be clearer, and more complete, by using multiple, smaller, `if` checks.

Here's something that worked for me.

```
// pseudo-code \\
if (top_win_count < 4)
  if (difference_between_wins == 0)
    compose "all" string
  else
    compose "player1 score - player2 score" string
else if (wins_diff > 1)
  compose WINS string
else if (wins_diff > 0)
  compose ADVANTAGE string
else
  "DEUCE"
```

The entire method can be written in less than 20 lines of code.

Comment: A good way of implementing this would be a state machine where each successive point transitions to a new state. Unfortunately, for a *really* beautiful functional implementation of state machines, you need proper tail calls, which Scala doesn't have as a language feature. They *are* available in the library, but it's not as nice as having them built into the language.

Comment: @JörgWMittag answer's is, imho, a better one because it gives some indications on how to solve the problem in a more "FP" way. But note that Scala is not an exclusive FP language, you can mix both the OO and FP way of programming.